# Facebook SDK keeps crashing android app

Tags: android, facebook, sdk, crash

Okay so i'm trying to implement the Facebook SDK into my Android app. Problem is, when i use the code explained within the Facebook documentation, my app just crashes with no error messages.

Heres the code im currently using (from the Facebook documentation):

```
// start Facebook Login
        Session.openActiveSession(this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() 
        {
            // callback when session changes state
              @Override
              public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) 
              {
                if (session.isOpened()) 
                {           
                    // make request to the /me API
                    Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() 
                    {
                        // callback after Graph API response with user object
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) 
                        {
                            if (user != null) 
                            {

                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
              }
        });
```

Comment: please post the logCat, without seeing this, it´s hard to know

Comment: might test if(session!=null&&...), post more code and logCat , then we can know more. thx.